# mysql show month as 0 if no amount is donated for a month

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like this:

```
id course_id amount created_on
1  2         100    2018-01-03
2  1         300    2018-03-03
3  2         200    2018-01-03
4  4         400    2018-04-03
```

I would like to pass the course id and get total amount for that course donated for a year, based on month wise. If no donation is made for a month need to show it as 0

output as below:

```
month amount
1     300
2     0
3     200
4     400
5     0
6     0
7     0
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
12    0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? That should not be that difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a calendar month table for this, because there is no guarantee that your current table has data for every month.

```
SELECT
    t1.month,
    COALESCE(t2.amount, 0) AS amount
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS month UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 UNION ALL
    SELECT 12
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(created_on) AS month, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY MONTH(created_on)
) t2
    ON t1.month = t2.month
ORDER BY
    t1.month;
```

Comment: Thank you dear friend i got what i wanted, was trying from this morning now i got it with ur help..!